# Why inserting the same image object twice in html does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, object

I'm trying to insert the same image into two different divs. But the image is only displayed in the last one. It looks like the same object can only appear once in html.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = '/image1.jpg';
img.onload = function(){
   $('#div1').html(img);
   $('#div2').html(img);
}
```

Only #div2 display the image.

Update to add code snippet

```js
var img = new Image();

img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
img.onload = function(){
    img.id = '#jcrop-target';
    $('#jcrop').html(img);
    img.id = '#jcrop-preview';
    $('#preview').html(img);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jcrop"></div>
<div id="preview"><div>
```

I used this solution, but it seemed very inelegant.

```js
var img = new Image();

img.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150';

img.onload = function(){
   $('#jcrop').html('<img id="jcrop-target" src="'+img.src+'" />');
   $('#preview').html('<img id="jcrop-preview" src="'+img.src+'" />');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jcrop"></div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Please add a codepen/jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Image()` constructor creates a new HTMLImageElement instance. It is functionality equivalent to `document.createElement('img')`. This creates a node in DOM tree structure complete with its dimensions and properties. It also has a specific position in the tree structure. It can't be at two different places in the tree structure. So you will have to make another element if you need, or you can try to clone it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use class instead of id if you need to place image in multiple `div` elements.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = '/image1.jpg';
img.onload = function(){
    $('.div').html(img);
}
```

so that you can add same image in multiple `div`

```
<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div" id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```js
var elem1 = document.createElement("img");
elem1.setAttribute("src", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
var elem2 = document.createElement("img");
elem2.setAttribute("src", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(elem1);
document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(elem2);
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Replace `http://via.placeholder.com/350x150` with your source `/image1.jpg`